# Creating Custom Index through C# in Sitecore 6.5

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I want to create custom index in Sitecore 6.5 through C#. I read this link: [Creating Index through .Config](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/using-the-sitecore-open-source-advanceddatabasecrawler-lucene-indexer/)

But I want to create custom index through C#, not any .config files. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "create" the index via C#, you can only query and work with it in C#. In order to "have" an index it must be defined via configuration which defines the properties of how the index should exist, e.g. item types to include, fields to include, root path to begin indexing at, etc.

Comment: +1. It's actually very easy to create an index from C# using strait-up Lucene.Net. Getting it to play ball with Sitecore would be another story.

Comment: @Derek: As Alex mentioned in his blog too, in SC 6.5 we are deleting the old search index and implementing the new through .config file. Is that true?

Comment: @Wanna, it's true that the API and the way it indexes has changed. However, it still uses Lucene under the hood if I am not mistaken. Both the new and the old still require that you define your indexes in the .config file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(_path, new StandardAnalyzer(), true);
writer.SetUseCompoundFile(true);
Lucene.NET.Documents.Document doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("Field1Name", yourField1Value, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("Field2Name", yourField2Value, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
writer.AddDocument(doc);
writer.Optimize();
writer.Close();
```

"yourFieldsValue" will probably come from Sitecore Item[] but it doesn;t have to.
If you point _path to the non-system index existing in web.config or add it there,
you will be able to see results in Sitecore content any index viewer tool. 
To utilize this index use Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher.Search() method.